# WordPress WP Query with post type other then default is not working

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type

The code shown below is not working, when I search, however if I remove the `post_type` the below works fine for default post.

**weblinks** is the custom post type for the taxonomy **weblinks_guidelines**

If any thing is searched:

```
 <?php if(!empty($_POST['search'])) {
    $search_term = $_POST['search'];
 } else {
   $search_term ='';
 }

 Arguments for the query
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'weblinks',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    's'=>$search_term
);
$my_query = new WP_Query ($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
 while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

 endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: What is in $_POST['search'], try to debug ,
change !empty to isset or try this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/how-to-create-a-custom-search-for-custom-post-type

Comment: I already added if(!empty($_POST['search'])){ ....

I have text field where If I type then save that keyword here and pass it to the wp_query as an arguemnt

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the sentences are added for our benefit, if not they're not properly commented out. I'd also consider cleaning up your code, the inconsistent indentation will be a pain to deal with later.

That said, your issue is that you're always searching for something, considering the `s` key is always included in the `$args` array, you need to add that whole argument conditionally, not just its value. Right now it will be either "search for nothing" or "search for the posted `'search'` value. We can fix this by pushing the `['s']` argument into the `$args` array using the basic syntax of `$array['key'] = $value;`.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'weblinks',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

if( !empty( $_POST['search'] ) ){
    $args['s'] = $_POST['search'];
}

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
     while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); 
         // Post Loop Code Here
     endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Dear, yes those sentences were for comments forgot to // in this post. I added the condition the same way you explained, but still none records is found

Comment: I thinks search is somewhere conflicting with the custom post_type

Comment: I am doing this code in custom page templates, does it make difference?